# How to Update Tikz/pgf and Tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

I am apparently running a very old version of tikz and tikz-cd. My computer shows:

> Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
>
> Package: tikz-cd 2012/03/18 v0.2b Commutative diagrams with tikz.

However, I went straight to the CTAN website and downloaded the latest version they have of both `tikz/pgf` as well as `tikz-cd`, and they are sitting nicely in my Latex folder. But latex is still showing these old packages in my `.log` file.  And I am still getting the same error which started all this (which is definitely due to an old version of these things).

I'm wondering if one has to "clear" whatever old packages I was using before I downloaded the new ones from CTAN?

Is there a simple way to do this?  I don't understand anything at all about computers and any fancy computer jargon will fly straight over my head, sadly.  I do know that my TexLive Utility is giving me the following confusing message:

> "The repository at http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet has TeX Live 2018, but you have TeX Live 2012 installed.  You need to switch repositories in order to continue."

Any suggestions here?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Updating packages by downloading it from CTAN might give you the latest version of the package, but as most packages rely on other packages providing their features to be used, you would have to update a lot of packages - especially with such an old version as TeX Live 2012. You should rather consider installing a recent TeX Live instead which might fix your problems. If a complete TeX Live update does not fix them, ask a new question with the exact MWE and error message(s) you get.

Comment: are you using Linux windows or mac? And you can google how to find which version you are using.

Comment: Guessing you have Mac TeX, though possibly Windows. You need to download the installer for TeX Live 2018 and install the current distribution. You don't need to remove the 2012 version, you can keep that one in case something goes wrong, as a fall back. If you are using Mac TeX, however, you might find that you OS is incompletely supported or unsupported, so check which version of Mac TeX is available for your system.